# I can't bind my S-FHSS Corona SBUS receiver with a jumper t16 transmitter. Are they compatible?

Tags: jumper, t16

It says jumper t16 is S-[FHSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-hopping_spread_spectrum) compatible. I put my [Corona](http://www.corona-rc.com/intro/1.html) receiver into SBUS mode, but I can't get them to bind. Are the two compatible?

[image]

Comment: I don't have this RX so I can't answer the question directly, but this is not an official S-FHSS licensed RX, likely the protocol was reverse engineered. The T16 module uses a reverse engineered protocol as well, so if they both made slight mistakes in their reverse-engineering, it is possible something is preventing them from binding correctly. The T16 seems to work fine with the offical Futaba S-FHSS recievers I have around otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bought 2 of R6SF and both of them got bind to T16P V2.
I actuary had same trouble with you, and  bought another one. Both of them seem would not bind. Trying to update internal module firmware did not work out. But I finally did it with RF Freq. fine tune. It written on Jumper Website

Comment: thank you. do you have a link ?

Answer (score 4):

There could be many reasons why it won't bind.  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a clear reason.

Did you follow the binding instructions in the Corona R6SF manual?

http://img.banggood.com/file/products/20160907060650R8SF%20R6SF%20and%20R4SF%20Instruction%20manual%20V1.2.docx

You might also try to upgrade the Jumper T16 internal multi-protocol module firmware.  Here is a link to a video by Joshua Bardwell that outlines the process.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qT_wmbxTBp8